# Find all executable files and copy (along with folder) to some dummy folder using bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to collect all executable from  folders and trying to copy them into dummy folder. I tried few things using find but some reason it is copying .txt files too

Comment: Show us what you've tried!

Comment: sudo find srcFlder -perm /a+x -exec cp -r {} destinationFolder \;  I tried this but its copying text files too

Comment: `find` files `-type f` that are executable `-executable`. `its copying text files too` The file _content_ is unrelated to if it is executable. If may be any file, you want to copy executable ones - the ones with executable permission set. Do you want to also restrict the content of the file? If so, how.

Comment: If your text files are executable they are copied too, and this is normal. If they are not, please show us an example and provide the permissions of the file that should not be copied. Note that, as @KamilCuk noted, you should use `-type f` if you want to copy only files, not directories. And you should remove the `-r` option of `cp`.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not that simple, you know:

```
find ./ -executable
```

On my PC, I get following results:

```
./20211214/Logs/2021-02-13.log
./20211214/Logs/2021-02-14.log
./20211214/Logs/2021-02-15.log
./20211214/Logs/2021-02-16.log
./20211214/Logs/2021-02-17.log
```

... which is not that surprising:

```
ls -ltra 2021-02-17.log
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 usr usr 441793 Feb 26  2021./2021-02-17.log
```

As you can see: a file with extension "*.log" can be executable.

Answer (score 0):

It is copying `txt` files too because they are executable... But there are some more issues with your `find` attempt: it copies directories too, not just files.

And note that you could have several executable files with the same name in different sub-directories of your source directory, e.g., `srcFlder/bar/foo` and `srcFlder/baz/foo`. When copying them at destination the last one would overwrite the others.

If you want to copy only executable files that don't have the `.txt` extension, and you don't care about files with the same name you can try:

```
find srcFlder -type f -name '*.txt' -prune -o \
  -type f -perm /a+x -exec cp -f {} destinationFolder \;
```

If you have some more file extensions to exclude you can add them with:

```bash
find srcFlder -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.log' \) -prune -o \
  -type f -perm /a+x -exec cp -f {} destinationFolder \;
```

Finally, if you care about files with the same name, you could preserve the source hierarchy in the destination directory. To do so you must create the target directory (if it does not exist yet) before copying. So, if one of the found files is `srcFlder/bar/foo` you `mkdir -p destinationFolder/bar` before copying `srcFlder/bar/foo` to `destinationFolder/bar/foo`. Example with a small bash script as `exec` command:

```
find srcFlder -type f -name '*.txt' -prune -o \
  -type f -perm /a+x -exec bash -c 'f="${1/#srcFlder/destinationFolder}"; \
  mkdir -p $(dirname "$f"); cp "$1" "$f"' _ {} \;
```